# Side menu bar not extended to fill out the content of whole page (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do these changes to a GUI. Basically, the page consists of a left menu bar, that should extend when you hover over it, a center section with some nested content that potentially can be pretty long, and a right section. Now, the left menu bar looks a bit weird and stops earlier than the center. I've played around with some padding and height attribute settings, as well as changing the "position" attribute, without any success so far. I tried to remove the unnecessary stuff, but the code is still pretty long so here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6wLugvh7/21/

The problem is the center content might be of different lengths, depending on the choices the user make, so I can't set a fixed length. Some changes I did manage to make it look a bit better, but then the center section was sliding out when the menu bar was expanded.

Does anybody have any ideas? Might be something very simple I'm missing
Thanks in advance.

Code:

```js
    var path = "";
    var closedTocWidth = 70;
    var openedTocWidth = 500;
    var rightSectionWidth = 230;
    var isTocExpanded = false;
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
     closeToc();
     $("#docTree").html("");
     $("#docListContent").hide();
      
     
     $(".left").on('mouseleave', function() {
      if (event.relatedTarget == null) {
       event.stopPropagation();
       return;
      }
      if (isTocExpanded) {
       closeToc();
      }
     });
      $(".left").on('mouseenter', function() {
      if (event.relatedTarget == null) {
       event.stopPropagation();
       return;
      }
      if (!isTocExpanded) {
       expandToc();
      }
     });
     
    });
    
    function openDocument(oid, li) {
     return;
    }
    function expandToc() {
     var docWidth =  $(document).width();
    
     $(".left").attr("onclick", "");
     $(".center").attr("onclick", "closeToc()");
     
     $(".left").addClass("left-hovered");
     $("#docListContent").fadeIn(450);
     isTocExpanded = true;
     
    }
    function closeToc() {
     $(".center").attr("onclick", "");
     $(".left").removeClass("left-hovered");
    
     $("#docListContent").fadeOut(450);
     isTocExpanded = false;
     return false;
    }
    
    function toggleToc() {
     if(isTocExpanded) closeToc(); else expandToc();
    }
```

```css
    @font-face {
        font-family: avenir;
        src: url(/fonts/Avenir/avenirtp-medium-web.woff);
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: avenir light;
        src: url(/fonts/Avenir/avenirtp-light-web.woff);
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: avenir black;
        src: url(/fonts/Avenir/avenirtp-black-web.woff);
    }
    * {
     font-family: avenir light, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    : root {
      --closedTocWidth: 70px;
      --openedTocWidth: 500px;
      --dark-blue: #000c63;
      --highlightTime: 0.2s;
      --expandTime: 3s;
      --expandFadeTime: 0.4s;
      --collapseTime: 0.4s;
      --collapseFadeTime: 1s;
    }
    html,
    body {
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       height:100%;
       overflow-y:scroll !important;
    }
    body {
     display: table; 
     width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%; 
     font-size: 11px;
     overflow-y:scroll !important;
    }
    header {
     display:block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 70px;
     position: absolute;
     AAborder: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
     background-color: white; 
    }
    #tpLogo {
     border: none;
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-top: 6px;
     height: 55px; 
    }
    #logoText {
     color: #000099;
     vertical-align: 20px;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin-left: 10px;
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: bold;
    }
    #supportText {
     color: #000099;
     vertical-align: 20px;
     text-decoration: none;
     float:right;
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-top:25px;
     margin-right:30px;
    }
    header a {
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    footer {
     z-index: 1;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: white;
     border-top: 2px solid #999;
     font-size: 0.9em;
    }
    
    /* Main page*/
    #tourWrapper {
     background-color: #F8F8F8;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     top: 0;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 10px 0 0 0;
     color: #000099;
    }
    #tourContent {
     top: 0px;
     left: 80px;
     margin-right: 50px;
     padding: 50px 0 100px 30px;
     width: 80%; 
     position: relative;
     color: #000c63;   /*IE compability*/
     color: var(--dark-blue);/*Variable to facilitate easier testing of GUI changes*/
     font-size: 1.5em;
     border-spacing: 3px;
    }
    .tourParagraph {
     color: #999999;
     margin: 0 0 40px 0;
     width: auto;
    }
    .tourRow {
     display: table-row; 
     vertical-align: top;
    }
    .tourCell {
     display: table-cell; 
     vertical-align: top;
     border-bottom: 30px solid transparent; 
    }
    #tourContent img {
     height: 100px; 
     margin-left: 20px;
     display: table-cell;
    }
    footer div {
     z-index: 4;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #999;
     margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
    footer span {
     font-weight: normal;
     margin: 10px 5px 10px 110px;
    }
    #centerContent {
     position: relative;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     margin-top: 0px;
     height: 100%;
     right: 0;
     width: 100%;
    }
    .infoDiv {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #FFC160;
     padding: 5px;
     z-index: 7877;
     font-size: 12px;
     top: -20px;
     left: 50px;
     min-width: 120px;
    }
    .infoDiv ul {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 2px;
    }
    .infoDiv li {
     margin: 2px;
    }
    /* SECTION PLACEMENT */
    main {
     width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: table-row;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    section {
     position: relative;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     vertical-align: top;
    }
    section.left {
     display: table-cell;
     position: relative;
     top: 70px;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     min-height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     padding-bottom: 100px;
     z-index: 3;
     
     width: 70px;
     max-width: 70px;
     min-width: 70px;
     width: var(--closedTocWidth);
     max-width: var(--closedTocWidth);
     min-width: var(--closedTocWidth);
     
     background-color: #000c63;
     background-color: var(--dark-blue);
     -webkit-transition: width 1s, max-width 1s, min-width 1s;
     -moz-transition: width 1s, max-width 1s, min-width 1s;
     -o-transition: width 1s, max-width 1s, min-width 1s;
     transition: width 1s, max-width 1s, min-width 1s;
     
     -webkit-transition: width var(--collapseFadeTime), max-width var(--collapseFadeTime), min-width var(--collapseFadeTime);
     -moz-transition: width var(--collapseFadeTime), max-width var(--collapseFadeTime), min-width var(--collapseFadeTime);
     -o-transition: width var(--collapseFadeTime), max-width var(--collapseFadeTime), min-width var(--collapseFadeTime);
     transition: width var(--collapseFadeTime), max-width var(--collapseFadeTime), min-width var(--collapseFadeTime);
    }
    section.left-hovered {
     display: table-cell;
     
     width: 500px;
     max-width: 500px;
     min-width: 500px;
     
     -webkit-transition: width 0.4s, max-width 0.4s, min-width 0.4s;
     -moz-transition: width 0.4s, max-width 0.4s, min-width 0.4s;
     -o-transition: background-color 3s, background-image 0.4s, width 0.4s, max-width 0.4s, min-width 0.4s;
     transition: background-color 3s, background-image 0.4s, width 0.4s, max-width 0.4s, min-width 0.4s;
     
     -webkit-transition: width var(--expandFadeTime), max-width var(--expandFadeTime), min-width var(--expandFadeTime);
     -moz-transition: width var(--expandFadeTime), max-width var(--expandFadeTime), min-width var(--expandFadeTime);
     -o-transition: width var(--expandFadeTime), max-width var(--expandFadeTime), min-width var(--expandFadeTime);
     transition: width var(--expandFadeTime), max-width var(--expandFadeTime), min-width var(--expandFadeTime);
    }
    section.right {
     display: table-cell;
     top: 70px;
     width: 230px;
     z-index: 1;
     min-width: 230px;
     max-width: 230px;
     background-color: #ebecef;
    }
    section.center {
     position: absolute;
     display: table-cell;
     top: 70px; 
     left: 70px;
     left: var(--closedTocWidth);
     bottom: 0;
     z-index: 2;
     background-color: none;
    }
    
    div.docListHolder {
     margin: 20px 20px 6px 0px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    ul.docList {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0px 0 0px 20px;
     padding: 0;
     right: 190px;
    }
    ul.docList ul {
     padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }
    ul#documentList {
     margin: 0px 0 0px 20px;
    }
    ul.staticDocList {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0px 0 0px 20px;
     padding: 0;
     right: 190px;
     text-transform: uppercase !important;
    }
    ul.docList {
     text-transform: uppercase !important;
    }
     
    ul.docList li, ul.staticDocList li, ul.docList a, ul.staticDocList a {
     font-family: avenir !important;
     color: white !important;
     line-height: 30px;
     cursor: pointer; 
     font-size: 14px;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
       overflow: hidden;
     font-weight: normal !important;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul.staticDocList ul { 
     padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    }
    .docTreeBranch {
     font-size: 14px;
    }
    .docTreeRootBranch>a {
     font-size: 16px; 
    }
    div.doclistHeader {
     background-color: #000956;
     padding:10px;
     height: 10%;
     color: white;
     text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    div.doclistHeader div {
     margin:5px;
     padding: 5px;
    }
    div.doclistHeader img {
     width:20px;
     height:20px;
     vertical-align:bottom;
     border:none;
    }
    #docListContent {
     width: 100%;
    }
    .sectionDiv {
     padding: 20px;
     color: white;
    }
    /* Right section */
    section.right {
     padding: 0px;
    }
    /* News List */
    ul {
     padding: 0; 
    } 
    #newslist {
        list-style-type: none;
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0 0 120px 0;
     padding: 0;
     width: 230px;
     -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    }
    .newsItemHeader {
     width: 200px;
     font-size: 20px;
     color: DarkGray;
     display: block;
     margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    }
    .newsHeader {
     background-color: #DDDDDD;
     height: 40px;
     width: 100%;
     vertical-align: middle;
     display: table;
     margin: 0;
     font-size: 14px;
    }
    .newsHeader div {
     display:table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: #666666;
    }
    
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 768px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
     div.outerHeader {
      height: 120px;
     }
     div.headerActions {
      top: 60px;
      bottom: 0;  
     }
     div.docContent {
      margin-top: 140px;
     } 
     div.innerHeader p {
      max-width: 50%;
      white-space: inherit;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-size: 16px;
     }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 1080px) {
     div.innerHeader p {
      font-size: 16px;
     } 
    }
    @media (max-width: 1280px) {
     div.innerHeader {
      font-size: 22px;
     }
     div.innerHeader p {
      max-width: 50%;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-top: 14px;
     }
     div.headerActions .btn-default {
      font-size: 10px;
     }
    }
    @media (min-device-width: 768px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Menu bar</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
    
    <script src="/js/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/doctree.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
     <header>
      <a href="/">
       <span id="logoText">Header</span>
      </a>
     </header> 
     <main>
      <section class="left" onmouseenter="expandToc()">
       <div id="doclist">
        <div id="docListContent">
         <div id="docListTabs">
          <ul>
           <li>
            <a href="#docListTabs-1">Links</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
          <div id="docListTabs-1">
          <br/>
           <div class="docListHolder">
            <ul class="docList">
            <li style="margin-left: 0px;">
             Links 1
             <ul class="docList" id="docTree">
             </ul>
              <li style="margin-left: 20px;"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li style="margin-left: 20px;"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li style="margin-left: 20px;"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li style="margin-left: 20px;"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li style="margin-left: 20px;"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li style="margin-left: 20px;"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li style="margin-left: 20px;"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            </li>       
           </div>
           <br/>
           <br/>
           <br/>
           <br/>
           <br/>
           <br/>
           <br/>
           <ul class="staticDocList">
            <li>Links 2
             <ul>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
             </ul>
            </li>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <li>Links 3
             <ul>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
             </ul>
            </li>
           </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </section>
      <section class="center">
       <div id="centerContent">
        <div id="tourWrapper">
         <div id="tourContent">
          <h3>This is a sample content to fill out the page<br/> My hope is that the blue menu bar to the left would follow this all the way to the bottom when scrolling down.</h3>
          <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <table border="0"><tr><td>repeated text</td></tr></table>
           <p style="border-spacing: 30px"><div style="border-spacing: 30px;line-height:30px;"></div><div></div></p>
         </div>
       </div>
       <footer>
        <div>
        Additional info
        </div>
       </footer>
      </section>
      
      <section class="right">
       <div class="newsHeader">
        <div>
         <p>Right section</p>
        </div>
       </div>
       <ul id="newslist">
       </ul>
       This right section should also stay at the same place when the menu is expanded
      </section>
      
     </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: To be clear, The blue box, has to stay in your screen, when not hovered small, or extended when hovered. Then when you scroll down it has to come down with you?

Comment: you need to give position fixed to sidebar if you want to make it fixed and then on hover change width to 100%

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. The blue ribbon should be small and extended when you hover over it. The "repeated text" in the middle section is a list that will have different lengths depending on what the user clicks on in the links. I want the blue menu to always cover the whole length of the page so that when you scroll down, there is no white space between the menu and the footer.

Comment: @Rahul Giving it position:fixed solves the problem, but introduces the new one that I can't scroll in the menu bar. In some cases in the real situation, the links expand so that the user's have a lot to choose from. If you set it to fixed and try to view it in a window with smaller size, you'll see that the bottom links becomes inaccessible.

Comment: I want it to behave as in position:relative, but extend the height as in position:fixed.